# AWS S3 behind Cloud front - how to access using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket sitting behind a CloudFront distribution.
I have managed to access files using signed urls.
I am trying to understand how can I access content using the AWS SDK from my c# code?

Without CloudFront i used the S3 client:

```
var m_S3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey, amazonS3Config);
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
{
     BucketName = bucketName,
     Key = keyName
};
GetObjectResponse response = await m_S3Client.GetObjectAsync(request)
```

But how do I do the same if the bucket is behind CloudFront distribution?

I tried using the `ServiceURL` in the `AmazonS3Config`.
Also looked into `AmazonCloudFrontClient`.
I don't find anything also in the documentations

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some more searching, there is no way to do so using the AWS nuget packages.
You simply have to use the CRUD operators with the CloudFront url using some `HttpClient`